# Configure qemu-1.4.2 on CentOS 6.2 with --enable-sdl

Tags: compilation, centos, sdl, qemu

I want to install qemu-1.4.2 on my CentOS 6.2. I downloaded the [source code](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/archive/v1.4.2.tar.gz), unpacked and ran `./configure --disable-vnc --enable-sdl`. Then it prompted it cannot find sdl:

```
ERROR
ERROR: User requested feature sdl
ERROR: configure was not able to find it
ERROR
```

Then I installed SDL and SDL-devel packages and ran `./configure` again. It still prompted it cannot find sdl. The following output showed that I have installed SDL packages, so why it still complains? Please help, I really need qemu to work on my project.

```
~/D/qemu-1.4.2 ❯❯❯ rpm -qa | grep SDL
SDL-1.2.14-6.el6.x86_64
SDL-1.2.14-6.el6.i686
SDL-devel-1.2.14-6.el6.x86_64
SDL-devel-1.2.14-6.el6.i686
~/D/qemu-1.4.2 ❯❯❯ which sdl-config
/usr/bin/sdl-config
```

These lines in config.log should relate to the issue:

```
cc -fPIE -DPIE -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector-all -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wempty-body -Wnested-externs -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Winit-self -Wignored-qualifiers -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wtype-limits -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL -o /tmp/siyuan/qemu-conf-31225-10750-20820.exe /tmp/siyuan/qemu-conf-9193-10750-15100.c -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -m64 -g -lSDL -lpthread
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/libSDL.so: undefined reference to `_XGetRequest'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems like a linking error, more clues to you:

```
/u/lib64 ❯❯❯ lsa libSDL.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 20 Sep 11 23:24 libSDL.so -> libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.3
/u/lib64 ❯❯❯ ldd libSDL.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa4d43000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff3dd306000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff3dd102000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff3dcee4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff3dcb50000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000318da00000)

~/D/qemu-1.4.2 ❯❯❯ sdl-config --libs
-lSDL -lpthread
~/D/qemu-1.4.2 ❯❯❯ pkg-config --libs sdl
-lSDL -lpthread
```

Comment: What does the `config.log` file say about the sdl test? Could it be an sdl version issue? Does `pkg-config --list-all` list sdl as found?

Comment: @EtanReisner I have updated the question with more information.

Comment: Please copy and paste text instead of using images. It is much simpler for everyone involved.

Comment: What does `sdl-config --libs` and/or `pkg-config --libs sdl` (or whatever entry it has for `pkg-config`, if any) output? A missing symbol usually means a missing link library. That either means you forgot to list something or something is broken (someone else forgot to list it). Also if you really are using CentOS 6.2 then your machine is **horribly** out of date and **full** of security vulnerabilities. Just for the record.

Comment: @EtanReisner sdl-config --libs shows `-lSDL -lpthread`

Comment: @StrikeW any luck (after 2 years)? I'm having the same problem.